# The fundamental groups of 3-dimensional spherical space forms

Tags: group-theory, geometric-topology, orthogonal-matrices, low-dimensional-topology

Let $S^3/\Gamma_i\,(i=1,2)$ be a $3$-dimensional spherical space form, where $\Gamma_i \subset SO(4)$ is a finite subgroup acting freely on $S^3$. If $S^3/\Gamma_1$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^3/\Gamma_2$, can we find a $g \in SO(4)$ such that
$$
g\Gamma_1 g^{-1}=\Gamma_2?
$$

Comment: On the other hand, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostow_rigidity_theorem.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in general, in fact it can fail for the [lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space) which are the quotients 
$$L(p;q) = S^3 / \Gamma(p;q)
$$ 
where $\Gamma(p;q)$ is the cyclic subgroup of order $p$ in $SO(4)$ that is generated by the element described, in complex coordinates, by the formula
$$(z_1,z_2) \mapsto (e^{2 \pi i/p} \cdot z_1, e^{2 \pi i q/p} \cdot z_2)
$$
The link given explains how to determine when $L(p;q_1)$ and $L(p;q_2)$ are homotopy equivalent and when they are homeomorphic, and these do not match up. And if they are not homeomorphic then there cannot be any $g \in SO(4)$ for which $g \Gamma(p;q_1) g^{-1} = \Gamma(p;q_2)$, because the map of $SO(4)$ determined by $g$ would descend to a homeomorphism between $L(p;q_1)$ and $L(p;q_2)$.